# Android: Fatal Exception (NotSerializableException) when quitting an activity that serializes objects in onSave/onRecall 

Tags: android, exception, serialization

I am developing an app that uses some custom classes as members.
I have implemented serialization/de-serialization in the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods.

It all works fine when rotating the screen (app is destroyed and re-created) and my objects are restored. 
However, when pressing the home button, the app crashes in the onPause method (which I have not modified)...

Any clue as to what's happening?

Here's a code sample that reproduces the issue

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class InvestigateError extends Activity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MYERROR";
    protected ShowInfo myShowInfo;

    protected class ShowInfo implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public String title;
    }

    public void populateMembers()
    {
        myShowInfo = new ShowInfo();
        myShowInfo.title = "Was I serialized???";
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if(savedInstanceState == null)
            populateMembers();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Activity created");

    }

    /* Save members */
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"__ SAVEINSTANCE __");
        outState.putSerializable("myshowInfo", myShowInfo);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

    /* Restore members */
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"__ RECALLINSTANCE __");
        myShowInfo = (ShowInfo) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("myshowInfo");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"string from object: " + myShowInfo.title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"__ DESTROY __");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"__ PAUSE __");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"__ STOP __");
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Here's the beginning of the stack trace

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.esquared.InvestigateError.InvestigateError$ShowInfo)
>
> > at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1160)
> >
> > at ndroid.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1114)
> >
> > at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:479)
> >
> > ...

Comment: Can you show the serialization code for ShowInfo (I assume that is what is being serialized)?

Comment: The code you see is all there is to it. There's no extra method in the ShowInfo class, only members. I assumed the class would by default be serialized to an array of bytes... am I wrong? Does it need extra methods for the serialize/un-serialize process?

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed the fact that it was an inner class.  Not sure what the issue is then.  It might help if you show the whole stacktrace.  Also, try using Parcelable instead of serializable.  Its a bit more work, but significantly faster.

Comment: I replaced the internal ShowInfo class with a Parcelable implementation of it and the error does not happen anymore. Since this provides the functionality I needed, it looks like you've resolved my issue! Thanks!

Comment: Also consider the answer in this issue report of similar nature: [Issue 8513](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8513) Just like Mayra did it recommends Parcelable. It also says that it will only work if the class is a static inner class, i.e an outer class will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 choices:

1. Make the outer class serializable as well.
2. Make your serializable inner class static.
3. Create another class and make that class serializable (don't serialize an inner class).

First one is actually discouraged.

And as Mayra mentioned, it will work faster if you implement Parcelable.

Comment: Could you explain or briefly point me to why the outer class has to be serializable? I don't know why the Activity class should be serialized at any point in the app's lifecycle... Is there some key mechanism I'm missing here?

Comment: For the mechanism behind, refer to the note here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4539

Comment: Thanks, this explains the necessity for the outer class to be serializable. It seems Parcelable is a much better choice